# Soap WS with WSF/PHP as client and .NET as server

Tags: php, wso2, wsh

I have to call a SOAP WS on a .Net server, using (from my customer documentation)

```
SOAP 1.1
WS-Addressing (August 2004)
WS-Security 1.1
WS-Trust (February 2005)
WS-SecureConversation (February 2005)
WS-SecurityPolicy 1.1
```

I use WSO2 WSF/PHP (wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0.zip file), here is my client

```
function appel($rec_cert, $pvt_key, $sUrl)
{
$reqPayloadString = <<<XML
<ns1:echo xmlns:ns1="http://wso2.org/wsfphp/samples"><text>Hello World!</text></ns1:echo>
XML;
    $sPolicy = dirname(__FILE__) . '/policy.xml';
    $sAction = "http://www.aaa.fr/SendMessage";
    $reqMessage = new WSMessage($reqPayloadString, array("to" => $sUrl, "action" => $sAction));

    $policy_xml = file_get_contents($sPolicy);
    $policy = new WSPolicy($policy_xml);
    $sec_token = new WSSecurityToken(array("privateKey" => $pvt_key, "receiverCertificate" => $rec_cert));

    $client = new WSClient(array(
        "useSOAP"=>1.1, 
        "useWSA" => 1.0,
        "policy" => $policy, 
        "securityToken" => $sec_token,
    ));

    $resMessage = $client->request($reqMessage);

    printf("Response = %s \n", $resMessage->str);
}
```

On my local webservice, it run fine, but just throw an Exception "Error , NO Response Received" on my customer preproduction server. I just don't use the same keys and certificates, as I have not the customer secret key.

Here is my local webservice

```
<?php 

function echoFunction($inMessage) {
    $returnMessage = new WSMessage($inMessage->str);
    return $returnMessage;
}

$pub_key = ws_get_cert_from_file("/var/www/samples/security/keys/alice_cert.cert");
$pvt_key = ws_get_key_from_file("/var/www/samples/security/keys/bob_key.pem");

$operations = array("echoString" => "echoFunction");

$actions = array("http://www.aaa.fr/SendMessage" => "echoString");

$policy = new WSPolicy(file_get_contents("policy.xml"));
$sec_token = new WSSecurityToken(array("privateKey" => $pvt_key, "receiverCertificate" => $pub_key));

$svr = new WSService(array(
    "actions" => $actions,
    "operations" => $operations,
    "policy" => $policy,
    "securityToken" => $sec_token));

$svr->reply();
```

The big problem is this error happened for a non-existant url, a different policy between client and server, and severals others errors I can create on my server.

There is a first evidence, from the wsf_php_client.log :

```
[Mon Jan 28 15:49:02 2013] [error] assertion_builder.c(510) [neethi] Unknown Assertion RampartConfig with namespace http://ws1.apache.org/rampart/policy
[Mon Jan 28 15:49:02 2013] [error] engine.c(548) [neethi] Assertion creation failed from element.
[Mon Jan 28 15:49:02 2013] [error] engine.c(145) [neethi] All creation failed
[Mon Jan 28 15:49:02 2013] [error] engine.c(473) [neethi] All creation failed from element.
[Mon Jan 28 15:49:02 2013] [error] engine.c(190) [neethi] Exactlyone creation failed.
[Mon Jan 28 15:49:02 2013] [error] engine.c(496) [neethi] Exactlyone creation failed from element.
[Mon Jan 28 15:49:02 2013] [error] engine.c(285) [neethi] Policy creation failed.
```

and a second one (I am searching about this)

```
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [info]  Starting addressing out handler
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [debug] http_transport_sender.c(241) ctx_epr:https://recette.customer.fr/securit.svc
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [debug] http_transport_sender.c(776) using axis2 native http sender.
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [debug] http_sender.c(494) msg_ctx_id:urn:uuid:ef0a33e6-695d-1e21-2453-d43d7e273c95
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [debug] http_transport_utils.c(3794) No session map stored
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [info]  [ssl client] CA certificate not specified
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [error] ssl/ssl_utils.c(50) Cannot find certificates
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [error] ssl/ssl_stream.c(99) Error occurred in SSL engine
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [error] http_client.c(294) Data stream creation failed for Host recette.customer.fr and 443 port
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [error] http_client.c(560) Client data stream null or socket error for host recette.customer.fr and 443 port
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [error] http_client.c(562) A read attempt(HTTP) for the reply without sending the request
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [error] http_sender.c(1303) status_code < 0
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [error] engine.c(171) Transport sender invoke failed
[Mon Jan 28 16:18:13 2013] [error] /home/cedric/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/src/wsf_client.c(1696) [WSF/PHP] Response Payload NULL( Error number and code) => : 76 :: A read attempt(HTTP) for the reply without sending the request
```

Where can I find more information to resolve my problem? I already ask the customer to tell me if he have any trace of my WS calls (but I still have no answer for now).

Comment: I have added WS-SecureConversation, it run fine on my local webservice. My big question : why I have an error wich does not help me to understand?

Answer (score -1):

I think your server doesn't start SSL communication with remote server. This can happen if it cannot trace it's certificate to root certificate authority that it knows (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate).

Usually you can either disable this chechk (if you would use CURL for example), or better - provide path to ca.crt file.. by default Apache should know where it is.. for example its configuration might include

SSLCACertificateFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/keys/ca.crt"

(as mentioned in http://wso2.org/library/articles/ssl-enabled-web-services-apache-axis2-c)

Comment: The server is a .Net one, not an apache. I use apache/axis2 via WSF/PHP on the client side, and the server is a customer's one (it is part of the problem, I don't own it). The error about CA not found is on the client side, and is since resolved. My main concern is about having a timeout on my client, and no clear error from the .Net server.